# Filter data frames with a non-constant shape by two string names - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter a data frame by two string names but the issue is that the strings can be in any one of the data frame's series and the number of series is variable. How can I filter each series of a data frame then consolidate them into one single data frame?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Directories of Statements:
cdir = "Current Directory"
odir = "Output Directory"

# Find all CSVs in cdir:
excels = [filename for filename in os.listdir(cdir) if filename.endswith(".csv")]

# Define concat_csv Function:
def concat_csv(csv_file):
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cdir, csv_file), header=None, index_col=None) # Load CSV into dataframe
    df_final = pd.DataFrame() # Create empty dataframe
    for col in df_csv: # For all columns in the dataframe filter rows by string 1 or 2 then create new dataframe
        df_i = df_csv[(df_csv[col].str.contains("string1")==True) or (df_csv[col].str.contains("string2")==True)] # Use row if string equals string 1 or 2
        df_final = df_final.concat(df_i, axis=1) # Concat all rows that contain string 1 or 2 to a new dataframe

    # Send final dataframe to CSV in output directory:
    df_final.to_csv(os.path.join(odir, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file))[0] + ".csv"), encoding='utf-8')

# Apply concat_csv to all CSVs in cdir:
for f in excels:
    concat_csv(os.path.join(cdir, f))
```

**Here is the final code I used after Scott Boston's recommendation:**

```
...
# Define concat_csv Function:
def concat_csv(csv_file):
    df_csv = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(cdir, csv_file), header=None, index_col=None) # Load CSV into data frame

    df = df_csv[df_csv.isin(["string 1", "string2"]).any(axis=1)] # Filter data frame by UGL data
    df2 = df.dropna(axis=1, how="all") # Drop columns with all empty cells
    try:
        df_final = df2.set_index([0]) # Set index to column 1
    except:
        df_final = df2

# Send final dataframe to CSV in output directory:
df_final.to_csv(os.path.join(odir, os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(csv_file))[0] + ".csv"), encoding='utf-8')

# Apply concat_csv to all CSVs in cdir:
for f in excels:
    concat_csv(os.path.join(cdir, f))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

You have a dataframe with N number of series and you want to check to see if two strings appear in any of the series and build a new dataframe with just those rows.

Build generic data

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.choice(list('ABCDEFG'),size=26),'B':np.random.choice(list('FGHIJKLMN'),size=26)})
```

Find all records where 'G' or 'F' appears in any column

```
df_final = df[df.isin(['G','F']).any(axis=1)]

print(df_final)
```

Output:

```
    A  B
0   G  I
2   G  G
4   A  G
7   F  N
8   F  M
10  C  F
11  A  G
14  F  G
16  G  H
18  F  L
19  D  G
```